# Auto accept rsa key fingerprint from command line

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, rsa, known-hosts

I've tried `yes | ssh root@10.x.x.x` to try to accept the RSA key fingerprint, but am still prompted if I'm sure I want to connect. Is there a way to make this automatic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add these to your bash startup file, or similar:

```
 #
 #  ssh + scp without storing or prompting for keys.
 #
 function sshtmp
 {
     ssh -o "ConnectTimeout 3" \
         -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" \
         -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" \
              "$@"
 }
 function scptmp
 {
     exec scp -o "ConnectTimeout 3" \
         -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" \
         -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" \
         "$@"
 }
```

Then use `sshtmp`, or `scptmp` in place of `ssh` and `scp`.

**NOTE** If you do go down this road you'll not be alerted that a host-key has changed and will lose security.

Comment: Thanks `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@10.x.x.x` worked for me

Comment: how is this the answer?  The question was to accept the keys automatically, not ignore them!  If this is asked and answered here then how do I find an answer to the actual question "Accept keys automatically"?  Hate to do a downvote but come-on people, this is not the way stack-exchange should be!

Comment: @JohnnyB take a look at my answer. It is not the cleanest solution, but it actually permits the key to be automatically accepted

Answer (score 63):

OpenSSH 7.6 has introduced new `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` setting for exactly this purpose:

```
ssh(1): expand the StrictHostKeyChecking option with two new
   settings. The first "accept-new" will automatically accept
   hitherto-unseen keys but will refuse connections for changed or
   invalid hostkeys. This is a safer subset of the current behaviour
   of StrictHostKeyChecking=no. The second setting "n", is a synonym
   for the current behaviour of StrictHostKeyChecking=no: accept new
   host keys, and continue connection for hosts with incorrect
   hostkeys. A future release will change the meaning of
   StrictHostKeyChecking=no to the behaviour of "accept-new".
```

([OpenSSH 7.6 Release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6))

Comment: To save someone a few clicks, place "StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new" in ~/.ssh/config to get this to work.

Comment: Don't add accept-new in config file! This can be a security issue if connecting to a unknown host, it will accepted by default, exposing you to a man-in-the-middle attack.
If this setting is not set by default, that's because it's not safe!

Comment: @ClémentMoulin-SimpleRezo, not quite true: if you connect to a truly **unknown** host, you don't know its fingerprint anyway, so you will hit "yes, trust it".  I have yet to see somebody checking host fingerprints manually.  If you have fingerprints distributed separately (e.g., SSH bastion host of your company or something like this), it's better to put them into "`known_hosts`" file so that SSH client checks them for you.  So there are some use cases when this setting could lead to serious security implications, but they are pretty specific.

Comment: That's why SSH fingerprints can be distributed also by DNS, and of course, preferally using DNSSEC.
Definetly disagree with your last comment. Host identification is the MOST important part of identification.

Comment: I never said it wasn't.  But you have no way to identify the host you connect to for the first time and know nothing about, so I can't see any security benefits.  Yes, DNSSEC verification is nice, and if it exists and is enabled then there's an automated check, but I never met it in the wild (unfortunately).  I wouldn't recommend people enabling `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` by default for all hosts, but I don't see it as a breach either.

Answer (score 22):

**Using SSH Programmatically with known hosts key**

If what you want is to be able to use programmatically **AND avoid Man-In-The-Middle attack**, then I suggest you get the known fingerprint using the command `ssh-keyscan`. Example:

```
$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa github.com 2>/dev/null
github.com ssh-dss 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
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

Then you can forge a script to save it to a temporary file and use the `UserKnownHostsFile` option. 
The example below is a script, which can be called `ssh_github`:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTKEY='github.com ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBANGFW2P9xlGU3zWrymJgI/lKo//ZW2WfVtmbsUZJ5uyKArtlQOT2+WRhcg4979aFxgKdcsqAYW3/LS1T2km3jYW/vr4Uzn+dXWODVk5VlUiZ1HFOHf6s6ITcZvjvdbp6ZbpM+DuJT7Bw+                      h5Fx8Qt8I16oCZYmAPJRtu46o9C2zk1AAAAFQC4gdFGcSbp5Gr0Wd5Ay/jtcldMewAAAIATTgn4sY4Nem/FQE+XJlyUQptPWMem5fwOcWtSXiTKaaN0lkk2p2snz+EJvAGXGq9dTSWHyLJSM2W6ZdQDqWJ1k+cL8CARAqL+UMwF84CR0m3hj+wtVGD/J4G5kW2DBAf4/bqzP4469lT+dF2FRQ2L9JKXrCWcnhMtJUvua8dvnwAAAIB6C4nQfAA7x8oLta6tT+oCk2WQcydNsyugE8vLrHlogoWEicla6cWPk7oXSspbzUcfkjN3Qa6e74PhRkc7JdSdAlFzU3m7LMkXo1MHgkqNX8glxWNVqBSc0YRdbFdTkL0C6gtpklilhvuHQCdbgB3LBAikcRkDp+FCVkUgPC/7Rw==
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+                                                                                                                                      PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+    2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ=='

TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)
echo "$HOSTKEY" > $TEMPFILE

ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile $TEMPFILE" $@

rm $TEMPFILE
```

With this, you can just run `ssh_github` instead of `ssh` and it will connect even if there is no `known_hosts` file where you put the script.

Answer (score 6):

I just use:

```sh
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host
```

It can also be used with pssh:

```sh
pssh -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no -h list.text -l user -A -i "cmd"
```

Comment: This worked for me, is there a reason why it was down voted?  Also requires OpenSSH 7.6+

Comment: This is THE correct answer, directly answering the question in the context the asker frames . The relevant piece is ` -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.  There's a caveat - consider the security implications - especially if you're sticking this into a script you'll forget about. (And if you're routinely dealing with this in a lab environment, there's better ways - you probably want to look at provisioning the hosts with certificates or public keys)

Answer (score 4):

Use the StrictHostKeyChecking option, for example:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new $host
```

This option can also be added to ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new
```

The benefit to the `accept-new`option is that it will remember the host the first time you connect to it - and if it ever changes you will be warned.

This is not a blanket override. If host keys change you will still get a warning. If you absolutely do not care about getting MITM'ed you can use this instead:

```
ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $h
```

This is a terrible idea for obvious reasons - anyone can create a script that can just harvest your password and use it to take over the real host.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to add the host to ~/.ssh/known-hosts (and dont add duplicated ones) as guided [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1090385/41015)

e.g. adding `gitlab.com`

```
ssh-keygen -F gitlab.com || ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: In the case of logging into termux's dropbear the command `ssh-keyscan -p 8022 192.168.43.1 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` was enough for me; my aim was to allow to remain the old key to let me log into termux on the old smartphone too.

Answer (score 1):

My 5 cents, because no one mentioned it:

First my use case - several servers upload to single "upload" server given as hostname "upload.domain.com". Upload is made with rsync+ssh. I wanted to be able to change "upload.domain.com" and everything to continue to work.

I did config file in .ssh directory:

```
cat > .ssh/config <<[end]
StrictHostKeyChecking no
[end]
```

aka

```
echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

You do not need to remove `.ssh/known_hosts` file, it prints message, but works anyway.

---

## Update

I don't mean this to be crontab or something automatic.

I mean you have to create a file `.ssh/config` and put this line into it. Easiest way is via the command I show. You can use any other method thats easy for you, like text editors - `vi`, `pico` etc.

Comment: Overwriting .ssh/config with this single line? Sounds more like a prank to me., so luckily no one mentioned it before.

Comment: Wait, this is not a crontab. You do that only once. See the update

Comment: Okay, that adds more context. However this is just how ssh works -  see `ssh_config(5)` - and so I wonder what it adds to the answers that have the `StrictHostKeyChecking` setting already. It perhaps falls into comment territory ... and there was some earlier critique that `StrictHostKeyChecking no` is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you must add trusted host to file: `~/.ssh/config`

you can easily achieve it this way, just change the value of TRUSTED_HOST for your hostname

```
export TRUSTED_HOST="github.com" && {cat | >> ~/.ssh/config } <<EOF
Host $TRUSTED_HOST
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
   LogLevel ERROR
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

In dropbear ssh you can use `-y` option: i.e. try

```
ssh -y root@10.x.x.x
```

> **`-y`**    Always accept remote host key if unknown

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. It is convention to format commands as "`code`".

Comment: Strange but in the man I see the following - ```-y Send log information using the syslog system module. By default this information is sent to stderr.```

Comment: I see the same in man.

Comment: this isn't a valid ssh option ? Where did you copy/paste this from ?

Comment: This option only exists in dropbear SSH, not OpenSSH.