# ssh command line specify server host key fingerprint

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key, hostkey

Using `ssh` command line (OpenSSH), can I specify the server's host key fingerprint?

This is possible with winscp.com using (e.g.) `-hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 AA:BB:CC...etc`

I have read the man page a couple times, I apologize if I've missed the obvious there.

I do not want to just auto accept a host key, and I don't want to require the user to update their `known_hosts`, but rather specify the host key in some form on the command line.

Comment: -o UserKnownHostsFile might work with a temp file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no command-line option in OpenSSH to pass a host key fingerprint.

Though you can use a temporary file (with the same format as the `known_hosts`) and make the `ssh` use that using the `-o UserKnownHostsFile`:

```
ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile my_temp_known_host" host.example.com
```

See the [`ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) (for the `-o`) and the [`ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) (for the `UserKnownHostsFile`) man pages.

---

You may also consider using the `StrictHostKeyChecking yes`.

---

As suggested on [Auto accept rsa key fingerprint from command line](https://serverfault.com/q/638600/168875#818504), you could write a small script that would allow you to achieve that:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)
echo "$1" > $TEMPFILE

ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile $TEMPFILE" ${@:2}

rm $TEMPFILE
```

If you call the script `ssh_known_host`, you could use it, passing the key as the first argument:

```
ssh_known_host 'github.com ssh-dss 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' git@github.com
```

---

Btw, do not try to use `<()` shell construct with `UserKnownHostsFile`, like this:

```
-o UserKnownHostsFile=<(echo "hostname ssh-rsa ...")
```

It won't work. Possibly because the fd created by `<()` can be read only once, while `ssh` reads the file repeatedly.

Comment: thank you for your answer and advice using StrictHostKeyChecking. This solution will work for me.