# Securely add a host (e.g. GitHub) to the SSH known_hosts file

Tags: ssh

How can I add a host key to the SSH `known_hosts` file securely?

I'm setting up a development machine, and I want to (e.g.) prevent `git` from prompting when I clone a repository from `github.com` using SSH.

I know that I can use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` (e.g. [this answer](https://serverfault.com/q/132970/7027)), but that's not secure.

So far, I've found...

1. GitHub publishes their SSH key fingerprints at [GitHub's SSH key fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints)
2. I can use `ssh-keyscan` to get the host key for `github.com`.

How do I combine these facts? Given a prepopulated list of fingerprints, how do I verify that the output of `ssh-keyscan` can be added to the `known_hosts` file?

---

I guess I'm asking the following:

**How do I get the fingerprint for a key returned by `ssh-keyscan`?**

Let's assume that I've already been [MITM-ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) for SSH, but that I can trust the GitHub HTTPS page (because it has a valid certificate chain).

That means that I've got some (suspect) SSH host keys (from `ssh-keyscan`) and some (trusted) key fingerprints. How do I verify one against the other?

---

*Related: how do I hash the host portion of the output from `ssh-keyscan`? Or can I mix hashed/unhashed hosts in `known_hosts`?*

Comment: Why wouldn't it be secure for your use case?

Comment: `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is vulnerable to MITM. Is `ssh-keyscan` secure against MITM?

Comment: I fail to understand why I'm overly worried about somebody impersonating a stranger I've never met whom I'm trusting enough to write code I'm about to download and run...

Comment: Because this is *my* source code in a private repo on github, and I don't want a MITM (e.g.) introducing malicious changes when I push commits. That's just _one_ example.

Comment: I (for better or worse) choose to trust github. I don't choose to trust every random network link between me and them.

Comment: Well that's unquestionably a different use case than mine.  Makes perfect sense.

Comment: I don't fully understand why you want it so automated? Is it not possible for you to just hardcode Github's keys to your known_hosts/deployment scripts? And yes the keys that get returned from `ssh-keyscan` could be MITM'd. In the end, the point of known_hosts is "if keys match, proceed; otherwise give warning/prompt". So you should list the keys that you *know* are correct, and everything will work (until Github changes their keys, which hopefully won't happen for a while). HTH and that I didn't completely misunderstand it all :)

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: You could ask github to put their ssh sigs on a separate web server in a static file, in a separate data-center, as a secondary means of validating them.  I am sure they won't do this, but I have done this with certain orgs that were extra cautious and/or paranoid.  You could also email them what you see in ssh-keyscan and say, "Does this look like your server?"  You could even set up a repo where everyone checks in the sigs they see and compares.  That might be a fun side project.

Comment: "Is it not possible for you to just hardcode Github's keys to your known_hosts/deployment scripts?" -- no, because there might _already_ be a MITM. So I can't (even manually) trust those keys until I've verified them against the fingerprints.

Comment: Note: Subject of the meta question *[Getting attention for answers that have aways been incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329971/getting-attention-for-answers-that-have-aways-been-incorrect)*, about the two top answers being insecure.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It's not clear which answers that meta question refers to. The "top two" from June 24, 2019, might not be the same as the top two today. The [current accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/971922) is from June 18, 2019. Is that one of them? Or is this one considered secure?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The most important part of "securely" adding a key to the `known_hosts` file is to get the key fingerprint from the server administrator. The key fingerprint should look something like this:

```
2048 SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 github.com (RSA)
```

In the case of GitHub, normally we can't talk directly to an administrator. However, they put the key on their web pages so we can recover the information from there.

## Manual key installation

**1)** Take a copy of the key from the server and get its fingerprint. N.B.: Do this *before* checking the fingerprint.

```
$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | tee github-key-temp | ssh-keygen -lf -
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-f3847d63
2048 SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 github.com (RSA)
```

**2)** Get a copy of the key fingerprint from the server administrator - in this case navigate to the page with the information on github.com

1. Go to github.com
2. Go to the *help* page (on the menu on the right if logged in; at the bottom of the homepage otherwise).
3. In the *Getting Started* section go to *Connecting to GitHub with SSH*
4. Go to [Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection)
5. Copy the SHA256 fingerprint from that page into your text editor for later use.

**3)** Compare the keys from the two sources

By placing them directly one above the other in a text editor, it is easy to see if something has changed

```
2048 SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 github.com (RSA) #key recovered from github website
2048 SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJ3Gl7E1InsaspRomtxdcArLviKaEsTGY8 github.com (RSA) #key recovered with keyscan
```

(Note that the second key has been manipulated, but it looks quite similar to the original - if something like this happens you are under serious attack and should contact a trusted security expert.)

If the keys are different abort the procedure and get in touch with a security expert

**4)** If the keys compare correctly then you should install the key you already downloaded

```
cat github-key-temp >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Or to install for all users on a system (as root):

```
cat github-key-temp >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

## Automated key installation

If you need to add a key during a build process then you should follow steps 1-3 of the manual process above.

Having done that, examine the contents of your `github-key-temp` file and make a script to add those contents to your known hosts file.

```
if ! grep github.com ~/.ssh/known_hosts > /dev/null
then
     echo "github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
fi
```

You should now *get rid of* any `ssh` commands which have `StrictHostKeyChecking` disabled.

Comment: Why is the order of step 1 and 2 important?

Comment: What about [`if ! ssh-keygen -F github.com; then`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12137048/52499)?

Comment: @DanielGoldberg - if you check on the web server _before_ you take a copy of the key then an attacker may realise you did the check. If they do that then they can turn off their man in the middle attack before you detect it.  You will be safe this time, but they will keep trying until, some time in future, you forget to check.

Comment: @x-yuri that only works if you already connected to the host and you trust the connection you made before.  If in doubt, follow the above procedure anyway.

Comment: I mean, you do `grep github.com ~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Why not use a more specialized tool (`ssh-keygen`) that does just that, but also knows the format of the file?

Comment: okay @x-yuri I now understand your suggestion.  I think it's a correct and reasonable improvement. I'm going to have to think about it since it's got the disadvantage that the line in the file would then not match the line being added making things more difficult to check. I can't think of any clear risk from that right now.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what lines you're talking about. You add the line with `echo`. `ssh-keygen` only checks the ip/domain part, and won't change `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. I'm only suggesting to change the `grep` part.

Comment: According to `man ssh-keygen` the `-F` option does the following: "Search for the specified hostname in a known_hosts file, listing any occurrences found. This option is useful to find **hashed host names** or addresses ..." (my emphasis)

Comment: If you need to replace (possibly) stale host keys, you could use, for example, `[ -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts ] && ssh-keygen -R github.com` to remove any existing github keys, followed by `echo "$GITHUB_HOST_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` (assuming the key is stored in a variable called `GITHUB_HOST_KEY`).

Answer (score 48):

You can mix hashed/unhashed entries in your known_hosts file.

So if you want to add github key, you can just do :

`ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

If you want it hashed, add -H

`ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Note: this is vulnerable to MITM attack, it answers to the "Related" part of the question only.

Comment: What is the difference between hashed/unhashed? I know what hashing is, just not why it is applied in this context.

Comment: Hashing your entries allows you to hide information about the hosts you are used to connect to. Check the accepted answer at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56268/ssh-benefits-of-using-hashed-known-hosts

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Using ssh-keyscan is subject to a man in the middle attack which means that the key you store could be a key belonging to the attacker trying to break into your system.  Please see my answer for a way to check things.

Comment: Att. *[Getting attention for answers that have aways been incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329971/getting-attention-for-answers-that-have-aways-been-incorrect)* - *"the two top answers are actually insecure"*

Comment: This answer was written at the very beginning when the question was not very clear.
It is subject to the man in the middle yes, but I left it here as people keep voting +1, I guess it helps some. It also answers the "related" part of the question.

Answer (score 9):

Now that GitHub [provides their SSH keys and fingerprints via their metadata API endpoint](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-18-githubs-ssh-host-keys-are-now-published-in-the-api/) (as of January 2022), you can leverage the trust you have in GitHub's TLS certificate used on `api.github.com` (due to it being signed by a [certificate authority (CA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) which is in your system's trusted root certificate store) to securely fetch their SSH host keys.

If you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed you can do it with this one-liner

```shell
curl --silent https://api.github.com/meta \
  | jq --raw-output '"github.com "+.ssh_keys[]' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Or if you want to use Python

```shell
curl --silent https://api.github.com/meta | \
  python3 -c 'import json,sys;print(*["github.com " + x for x in json.load(sys.stdin)["ssh_keys"]], sep="\n")' \
  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: This answer relies on curl being correctly configured to reject fraudulent certificates. You can check that your curl is working right by doing `curl https://expired.badssl.com/` which should fail.

As long as that fails then this should be a great answer for the special case of github.

Comment: To quote curl's man page `By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure.` So as long as you don't add a `-k` or `--insecure` argument to the curl command above or a curl config file you're fine.

Comment: - I also saw that, however that's not the guaranteed default on _all_ installs of curl, just the default install. If the user, or someone else, has turned off the SSL check in the ~/.curlrc file then these checks will be turned off silently and then there will be a vulnerability in this process.

The original answer specifically asks for a "secure" way of doing this so I think that a certain level of extra care is important in answers to this question.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to manually fetch the keys using `ssh-keyscan`, verify them manually:

```
$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | ssh-keygen -lf -
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-libssh-0.7.0
2048 SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 github.com (RSA)
```

And add them to your script, which will then carry the "authoritative" public key.

Comment: I've got the keys like you said, how do I 'add them to my script'?

Comment: Either as a separate file or as a string in your script.

Comment: This answer is dangerous because hidden in the "verify them manually" is a whole difficult process.  I've added an answer below which atempts to explain how to do that and use the results safely.

Comment: Att. *[Getting attention for answers that have aways been incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329971/getting-attention-for-answers-that-have-aways-been-incorrect)* - *"the two top answers are actually insecure"*

Comment: This answer (I've chosen another one) isn't actually insecure, AFAIK. `ssh-keyscan` _is_ vulnerable to a MITM attack, but we verify it manually (by comparing the fingerprint against the one suggested in the question).

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I agree the answer could be interpreted securely - "verify them manually" isn't explained, but if you understand it to mean "following the instructions in the ssh manual page" then that would probably be fine.  The risk here is that someone might not understand that and could, for example, try insecure things like checking the key after logging in to the server.  That's why I called this answer "dangerous" and other one "insecure" - the detail of how you check manually is the important bit.  Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote simple script (add_to_known_hosts) to handle this:

It won't create duplicate entries in the known_hosts file, and it will check if the fingerprint matches one provided as second argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# The first argument should be hostname (or IP)
# The second argument should be the SSH fingerprint from the server admin.
# Example: add_to_known_hosts github.com SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8

host=$1
fingerprint=$2

ip=$(getent hosts $1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo $ip

keys=$(ssh-keyscan -t rsa $host $ip)

# Iterate over keys (host and ip)
while IFS= read -r key; do
    # Extract Host name (or IP)
    key_host=$(echo $key | awk '{ print $1 }')

    # Extracting fingerprint of key
    key_fingerprint=$(echo $key | ssh-keygen -lf - | awk '{ print $2 }')

    # Check that fingerprint matches one provided as second parameter
    if [[ $fingerprint != $key_fingerprint ]]; then
      echo "Fingerprint match failed: '$fingerprint' (expected) != '$key_fingerprint' (got)";
      exit 1;
    fi
    
    # Add key to known_hosts if it doesn't exist
    if ! grep $key_host ~/.ssh/known_hosts > /dev/null
    then
       echo "Adding fingerprint $key_fingerprint for $key_host to ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
       echo $key >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    fi
done <<< "$keys"
```

Comment: I think this looks like a good answer for some circumstances. There's a definite chunk of code here which might be better put into a code repository (e.g. GitLab) together with some tests so that it can be worked on and verified more easily.

Answer (score 2):

### Automating SSH Known_Hosts fingerprint check

I have been trying to do this in Python on Jupyterhub for a little while but @Michael's answer was really helpful!

*Let us be clear* -- by design this step to confirm a known host should *NOT* be automated given susceptibility to man in the middle attacks (more info [here](https://www.ssh.com/attack/man-in-the-middle), but it should be obvious why this is a concern).

#### Manually checking SSH RSA Fingerprint for GitHub.com with Python & Bash

The insecure workaround `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"` was alright for testing but glad to have an alternative.

- Notice I use `!` bang in Jupyter to invoke bash command for `ssh-keyscan` & `cat`

```python
# MANUALLY GET TRUSTED RSA FINGERPRINT FOR GITHUB
# https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

rsa_pubkey_fingerprint = 'SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8'

# Get the host rsa info for github, write to a file
# pipe to get the RSA FingerPrint, and finally write that fingerprint to file

!ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | tee ./github_ssh_test | ssh-keygen -lf - >> ./fingerprint_rsa
```

#### Assert Fingerprints match to confirm known hosts

You can now use a python assertion to ensure authenticity of our trusted RSA fingerprint vs the Scanned-over-your-internet RSA fingerprint:

```python
assert(rsa_pubkey_fingerprint == open("./fingerprint_rsa", "r").read().split()[1])

# if the assertion passes and the trusted matches the scanned
# it'll write to your known_hosts file!

!cat ./github_ssh_test >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts

# you are now good to test your SSH connection
!ssh -T git@github.com
```

Thanks and a much better workaround to ignoring the strict check!

Comment: Programmatic checking is a good way to go since it's unlikely to be fooled by a key that's been carefully chosen to be visually similar.  The newer version of the OpenSSH ssh command does something similar to this answer where, when connecting, you can paste a key in to the (yes/no) prompt telling you that the key is unknown and it will only connect if the key matches exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check if the key exists before generating a new one:

```
ssh-keygen -F github.com || ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

In addition, in my case I had to mention a specific port:

```
ssh-keygen -F "[<host>]:<port>" || ssh-keyscan -p <port> <host> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: This answer is wrong since it uses an unprotected ssh-keyscan command to get the key. It does not answer how to "securely" get a key.  Please do not use this answer.

Answer (score -2):

To generate the known_hosts file, after generating your private and public keys and copied the public key to site.com, you can do

```
ssh -T account@site.com
```

Comment: This answer is wrong since it uses an unprotected ssh command to get the key. It does not answer how to "securely" get a key. Please do not use this answer.